# How to styles PlotLines on Y axis in BarChart React HIghCharts ?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I Have a Bar chart and in Y axis i have three plot lines,I can change the color  of label and style the  labels but I cannot get my desired outcome.

This is my desired Outcome.

[image]

I want the styling of the leftMost labels on Highcharts Y axis, Please guide me how can i achieve this.

```
My current implementation :
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h2ma08dd/

Please feel free to edit this and help me to achieve this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make custom shaped label w/o use of html in highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121684/is-it-possible-to-make-custom-shaped-label-w-o-use-of-html-in-highcharts)

Comment: Can you please edit the jsfiddle please. I can't get that. That would be great, Thanks